# Problemas con atributos privados

Tags: java, poo, get, set

tengo problemas con el manejo de mis atributos privados, forzosamente tienen que ser privados, tengo mi clase carro que es como mi clase principal y también tengo mi clase llantas, en mi clase principal quiero tomar estos atributos y modificarlos con un setter ya que son privados, en el código que agrego intente modificarlos desde el programa pero no compila me marca los errores

The method setMarcaNeumatico(String) is undefined for the type Carro
The method setRin(String) is undefined for the type Carro

pero lo que quería hacer que esta comentado en el código, ya que tampoco me funciono al momento de compilarlo, lo que quiero hacer es que el usuario ingrese una cadena y esa cadena con ayuda del método setter modifique al atributo privado de la clase llanta y al momento de imprimirlo con ayuda de System.out.println getter muestre el nuevo valor de ese atributo. Creo que esto se entiende mas si ven lo que esta comentado en la clase Carro que es como la principal.

```
//import java.util.Scanner;

public class Carro {

    public void mostrarAuto() {

        System.out.print("\nMarca de neumatico: " + getMarcaNeumatico() + "\nNumero de rin: " + getRin());
}

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        /*
         * Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         * 
         * String mn, ri;
         * 
         * System.out.print("Marca del neumatico: "); mn = sc.nextLine();
         * System.out.print("Numero de rin: "); ri = sc.nextLine();
         * 
         * Carro carro2 = new Carro();
         * carro2.setMarcaNeumatico(mn);
         * carro2.setRin(ri);
         * 
         * carro2.mostrarAuto();
         * 
         */

         Carro carro2 = new Carro();

         carro2.setMarcaNeumatico("michelin");
         carro2.setRin("R14");

         carro2.mostrarAuto();

    }

}
```

A continuación agrego la clase donde se encuentran los atributos privados

```
public class Llantas {

private String marcaNeumatico;
private String rin;

public String getMarcaNeumatico() {

  return marcaNeumatico;

}

public void setMarcaNeumatico(String marcaNeumatico) {

  this.marcaNeumatico = marcaNeumatico;

}

public String getRin() {

  return rin;

}

public void setRin(String rin) {

  this.rin = rin;

 }

}
```

Estaré atento a sus respuestas :)

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que importar la clase llantas.
luego

```
llantas.tu_metodo()
```

o tambien puedes heredar la clase.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya encontré mi error.